# How do you efficiently send Integers from Arduino to a Visual Studio C# form to control a mouse on computer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialization, arduino

I am very new to all of this, so bear with me.

I am trying to create a makeshift vr headset where I send accelerometer values over Bluetooth using the serial port. These values will them be separated and plugged into the SetCursorPos function with a for loop with delays so it moves smoothly and doesn't give me motion sickness. Figured some background on what it is will help with the actual question.

The port.readline I am using returns a string, so I tried to do `int potValue = Int32.Parse(port.readline());`. However it says input string was not in correct format. I googled everywhere, tried `int potValue = Convert.Int32(port.readline());` with no luck either. So first question is how do I even send an int value sent from an arduino to my computer so I can plug it into a setCursor function.

Second question comes from removing the moving cursor and just trying to display the values on a form. I can get the values to display, however it lags so unbelievably bad that maybe 1 value every 30 some seconds gets displayed. Tried doing delays on the sending arduino, setup a stopwatch if statement to slow down the set text functions, but it was still laggy. Is there a way to work with Serial transfer that doesn't make my computer want to die?

Here is the Visual Studio form code I have so far. Followed a tutorial to get the mouse coords and display them which worked amazing, so I tried to use the library for this as well with less luck.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gma.System.MouseKeyHook;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MoveMouseAuto
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        public Stopwatch watch { get; set; }
        int potValue = 0;
        String strPotValue = "";

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError =true)]
        public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
        private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_Events;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Subscribe(IKeyboardMouseEvents events)
        {
            m_Events = events;

        }

        private void Unsubscribe()
        {
            if (m_Events == null) return;
            m_Events.Dispose();
            m_Events = null;
        }
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.Text == "ON")
            {
                button1.Text = "OFF";
            }
            else if (button1.Text == "OFF")
            {
                button1.Text = "ON";
                while (true)
                {
                    if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 200)
                    {
                        strPotValue = port.ReadLine();
 
                        //potValue = Convert.ToInt32(strPotValue);
                        //SetCursorPos(MousePosition.X + potValue, MousePosition.Y);
                        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
      
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            port.Open();
            Unsubscribe();
            Subscribe(Hook.GlobalEvents());

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Unsubscribe();
        }

        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
            {
                this.Close();
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
    }
}
```

And if needed, here is the Arduino code I wrote

```
int val;    

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.setTimeout(10);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(getValue());    
}

int getValue(){
  val = analogRead(potPin) - 500; 
  return val;  
}
```

I understand my question seems fairly vague but this is as specific as I can get with my very limited knowledge on the topic.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Regarding the parse problem: probably your input is not convertible to an integer. Try to debug or output the value to the console to find out what it is.
You could use Int32.TryParse() to counter potential parsing problems. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Maybe you need strip CR LF chars at end of string. For example by `trim()`